# Thymeleaf + Spring MVC - How to persist values from a list or enum on a form?

Tags: java, spring, drop-down-menu, enums, thymeleaf

I have a page that displays a list of sql connections. One of the fields in that table is the databaseType, which is defined in the enum:

```
public enum SqlDatabaseType {
    NONE("None"),
    MySQL("MySql"),
    SQLSERVER("SQLServer");
```

For creating and editing the object, I populate the select box with this:

```
<label th:for="databaseType">SQL Database Type:</label>
<select>
    <option th:each="databaseType : ${T(b.c.m.h.m.SqlDatabaseType).values()}"
        th:value="${databaseType}"
        th:field="*{databaseType}"
        th:text="${databaseType.databaseType}">
    </option>
</select>
```

The DTO object that populates that form is:

```
public class SqlPojo {
    private String id;
    private String description;
    private SqlDatabaseType databaseType;
    private String url;
    private String port;
    private String database;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    // getter and setters
```

The problem is that all String fields are persisted, but not the complex type one.

The table that lists all created objects is defined as:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center">description</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">databaseType</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">url</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">port</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">database</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">username</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">actions</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="pojo : ${pojoList}">
            <td style="text-align: center" th:text="${pojo.description}"/>
            <td style="text-align: center" th:text="${pojo.databaseType}"/>
            <td style="text-align: center" th:text="${pojo.url}"/>
            <td style="text-align: center" th:text="${pojo.port}"/>
            <td style="text-align: center" th:text="${pojo.database}"/>
            <td style="text-align: center" th:text="${pojo.username}"/>

            <td style="text-align: center" >
                <a th:href="@{/sql/edit(id=${pojo.id})}">
                    <img width="20px" height="20px" alt="edit" th:src="@{/assets/img/edit.png}" />
                </a>
                <a th:href="@{/sql/remove(id=${pojo.id})}">
                    <img width="20px" height="20px" alt="remove" th:src="@{/assets/img/delete.png}" />
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the rendered out is:

[image]

Before starting using Thymeleaf, I was using JSP, the table definition was very similar and I got the `databaseType` value with no problems.

Switching to Thymeleaf presented some nice visuals, but also a few problems, like this one, for enum and lists (to be mentioned in another question). What's the best solution in this case? Defining a converter? If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the enum, I got it working by doing:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label th:for="databaseType">SQL Database Type:</label>
        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{{databaseType}}">
            <option th:each="databaseType : ${T(b.c.m.h.m.SqlDatabaseType).values()}"
                    th:value="${{databaseType}}"
                    th:selected="${databaseType == T(b.c.m.h.m.SqlDatabaseType)}"
                    th:text="${databaseType.databaseType}">
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

For the list, solution was a bit different:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label th:for="ftpConnection">FTP Connection:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="ftpId" >
        <option th:each="ftpConnection : ${ftpList}"
                th:value="${ftpConnection.getId()}"
                th:text="${ftpConnection.getDescription()}">
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: can u explain why double brackets in th:field ?? {{databaseType}} ?? and what is the significance of ${T and b.c.m.h.m is yr package name to the class SqlDatabaseType correct ?