# Thymeleaf + Spring form - How load persisted select box values from controller to view?

Tags: java, spring, list, drop-down-menu, thymeleaf

In this [question regarding persisting select box elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525564/thymeleaf-spring-mvc-how-to-persist-values-from-a-list-or-enum-on-a-form) I managed to work my way around and persisting the selected entity on the select menu by passing it's id to the controller and passing it to my business layer and 
persisting as I intended.

The first listing is for an enum. This works nicely and the selected value gets loaded when editing the entity.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label th:for="databaseType">SQL Database Type:</label>
        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{{databaseType}}">
            <option th:each="databaseType : ${T(b.c.m.h.m.SqlDatabaseType).values()}"
                    th:value="${{databaseType}}"
                    th:selected="${databaseType == T(b.c.m.h.m.SqlDatabaseType)}"
                    th:text="${databaseType.databaseType}">
            </option>
        </select>
</div>
```

The problem is with the list objects that are defined as:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label th:for="ftpConnection">FTP Connection:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="ftpId" >
        <option th:each="ftpConnection : ${ftpList}"
                th:value="${ftpConnection.getId()}"
                th:text="${ftpConnection.getDescription()}">
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This question now is rather the opposite. When I click the entity's edit link, the select box are set to default entity value for the select box and, upon submitting, the default entity's id is passed onto the controller and it gets persisted.

How to make sure the selected value on the list is the one correctly loaded from the persisted entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label th:for="ftpConnection">FTP Connection:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="ftpId" >
        <option th:each="ftpConnection : ${ftpList}"
            th:value="${ftpConnection.getId()}"
            th:selected="${ftpList.contains(ftpConnection)}"                                
            th:text="${ftpConnection.getDescription()}">
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be great if you had some explanation for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you simply forgot about `th:field` attribute in your `<select>` element:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label th:for="ftpConnection">FTP Connection:</label>
<select class="form-control" name="ftpId" th:field="*{yourFieldName}" >
    <option th:each="ftpConnection : ${ftpList}"
            th:value="${ftpConnection.getId()}"
            th:text="${ftpConnection.getDescription()}">
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried that, no luck, though. But I got it fixed. I'm posting the answer for reference. Thanks!