# Thymeleaf + Spring dropdown persisted data in dropdown box selected

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, el

I have a large form where I saved parameters in the DB so the next time the user comes in, the previous selections are pre-selected in various dropdowns.

Similar to this post : [Thymeleaf + Spring form - How load persisted select box values from controller to view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557383/thymeleaf-spring-form-how-load-persisted-select-box-values-from-controller-t)

The main difference is I have tons of parameters and I am trying to make it a bit more generic.

Basically, I have a ParameterSet object in Java with a getParameterByName function and a contains method that check if the dynamic possible values of the dropdown were selected in the prior run.

My problem is probably related to Thymeleaf syntax. I have been playing with th:selected='${campaignRunCommand.parameterSet.parameters.getParameterByName("states").contains("${st}")}'
and I am no even sure it is possible to send static values no parameters inside Thymeleaf like that.

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" style="width: 75%"
id="cstates" name="cstates" multiple="multiple">
<option th:each="st : ${states}" th:value="${st}" th:selected='${campaignRunCommand.parameterSet.parameters.getParameterByName("states").contains("${st}")}'
    th:text="${st}"></option>
```

Comment: Use spring's model class to send the data from getParameterByName method. See [documentacion oficial](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, my problem was indeed a syntax issue and simple.

This contains("${st}")}' is not the proper syntax. You don't need to tell Thymeleaf this is a variable again inside that expression. .contais(st) worked fine.